# Generic base class implementation for both struct and object

Tags: c#, generics

I have this base class:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    public T Object { get; set; }
}
```

and this derived type:

```
public class OkResult<T> : Result<T>
{

}
```

that has this dervied type:

```
public class Ok : OkResult<Object>
{
}
```

To have a method with this signature as return:

```
        Result<Guid> Test()
        {
            return new OkResult<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
```

That I can use like this:

```
var test = Test();
if(test is Ok)
{ 
do something...
}
```

and also this (if you do the same with error)

```
var test = Test();
if(test is Error)
{ 
do something...
}
```

My problem is that it does not work for both structs and objects eventhough struct inherits from object, only for objects. I cannot cast a Result to Ok. Eventhough Ok inherits from OkResult

Is there any solution to this? I just want to check that what ever Im getting back is Ok.

Comment: It does through boxing, but can I get that to work with generics?

Comment: `return new Ok<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid());` You haven't defined a generic `Ok<>` type. Did you mean to write `OkResult<Guid>` here?

Comment: Sorry, yes, mixed copying code and writing in the question.Will fix it now.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I cannot cast Result<Guid> to Ok or at least not the way im doing it. Eventhough Ok is inheriting from OkResult<Object> and Guid inherits from Object.